# How to know a user can access node/{nid} and node/{nid}/latest in fastest way

Tags: 8

I have a view displaying list of latest node revisions.

The view has `title` field.

The website gives users permissions to access `node/{nid}`(shows latest revision if published default revision doesn't exist) and `node/{nid}/latest` (shows latest revision if defaut revision and latest revision is different) depending moderation state and user groups.

I want to override the view's title field according to the rules below:

- if current user can access `node/{nid}/latest` the title links to the page
- else if current user can access `node/{nid}` the title links to the page
- else show only title text

Dozens or hundreds of people may simultaneously access the view so I want to keep it fast to display. What is the fastest way to check those?

edit: 
I searched about `hook_node_grants` but it only supports view/update/delete operations so I think it can't hold data for `node/{nid}/latest`.
Should I store every pattern in table just like `node_access` table does and look up on it when view is updated?

Comment: Create 3 diff version of your block view. [Change the Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3DXz.png) for each to permission or user role whatever makes more sense to you. Cache your view, should be already turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the route name you can check access in PHP. For the second link you can use this route:

`\Drupal::service('access_manager')->checkNamedRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => '1']))`.

You can find the first one with the help of the Devel module when you click on *Current Route Info* while displaying the content and look for `[_route]`.

I would put the nid into the title field and override the field content in a preprocess hook. Display the link for each route if the access check returns true. Caching is no problem because caching is by default permission based.

Comment: It works like a charm! I made a field plugin using the service. Really appreciate your help!